# Question on Gaussian Normal Curvature .

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose two surfaces $M_1$ and $M_2$ interssect in a curve $\gamma$ .Let $\kappa $

be the curvature of $\gamma$ , $\lambda_i$ the normal curvature of $\gamma$ in $M_i$ , and $\theta $ the angle between the normals of

$M_1$ and $M_2$ .

Prove

$$\kappa^{2}\sin^2\theta = \lambda^2_1+\lambda^2_2 - 2\lambda_1 \lambda_2 \cos\theta$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have :$$\kappa_n=<T',n> \Rightarrow \kappa_n=<\kappa N,n>$$

Then $$\lambda_1 n_2=\kappa<N,n_1>n_2  \ \ \ (i)$$

And $$\lambda_2 n_1=\kappa<N,n_2>n_1 \ \ \ (ii)$$

Now subtract $(i)$ and $(ii)$ and then taking the dot product of the result with itself we have :

$$ \lambda_1^2<n_2,n_2>-2\lambda_1 \lambda_2<n_1 ,n_2>+\lambda_2^2<n_1 ,n_1>=\kappa^2|n_1 \times n_2|^2$$